# Showing a specific location using UIMapKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mapkit

I have an iPhone application with a number of views, each view represented a part of the world.  When my user taps the button to take them to that view, I want to show a map with a preset location...i.e. when the tap to go to New York it shows a map of New York

Is this possible to do?  Specify a latitude and longitude coordinate? or by some other method?

I have the following code so far which takes my users current location and displays the map of that, and i can choose between hybrid, normal or satellite through a segmented control.

```
-(IBAction)getLocation {
    creteMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
}

-(IBAction)setMap:(id)sender {

    switch (((UISegmentedControl *)sender).selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            creteMapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            creteMapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            creteMapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

That all works perfectly, but instead of the current location I want to just set a already defined one. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add class that implement MKAnnotation  protocol like : http://trac.ilesansfil.org/browser/branches/ilesansfil_iphone_app/STABLE_1.3/Models/LocationAnnotation.h

http://trac.ilesansfil.org/browser/branches/ilesansfil_iphone_app/STABLE_1.3/Models/LocationAnnotation.m

import header file 
and try

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate1;
    coordinate1.longitude = 3.35;
    coordinate1.latitude = 44.85;
    LocationAnnotation *loc1 = [[LocationAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate1];
    [creteMapView addAnnotation:loc1];
```

this will add a pin to your map

You can also remove user location if you want with :

```
creteMapView.showsUserLocation = NO;
```

Comment: Hi Someone, thanks for the reply. I get a cpl of errors with that - use of undeclared identifiers for LocationAnnotation and loc1

Comment: sorry I forgot to add a LocationAnnotation Class, I edited the post You can see links for this class implementation

Answer (score 0):

Use *setRegion* in your MKMapView. It needs a MKCoordinateRegion that you make with MKCoordinateRegionMake with a center coordinate (lat, long) and a span (area covered).
You can get the latitude and longitude from an API like Google maps, but that would need a full tutorial.

Comment: you can set the center also, which will keep the scale intact, just move the rect.

Comment: true, then you don't need to care about the 'span' part